# is this a bug of 32bit GHC on MAC

Tags: haskell, ghc

To make long stroy short,  my code is about parse a json file using [aeson](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson)

Here is my two pieces of code:

a.hs

```haskell
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as C
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative

data AuctionInfo = AuctionInfo {
    realm :: Realm ,
    alliance :: Auctions  ,
    horde ::  Auctions  ,
    neutral :: Auctions  
}   deriving (Show )

instance FromJSON AuctionInfo where
   parseJSON (Object o) = do
      r <- o .: "realm" >>= parseJSON
      a <- o .: "alliance" >>= parseJSON
      h <- o .: "horde" >>= parseJSON
      n <- o .: "neutral" >>= parseJSON
      return $  AuctionInfo r a h n
   parseJSON _ = mzero

data Realm = Realm { name2 :: String , slug:: String} deriving (Show )
instance FromJSON Realm where
      parseJSON (Object o) = Realm <$>
            o .: "name" <*>
            o .: "slug"
      parseJSON _ = mzero

data Auctions = Auctions {auctions :: [Auc]} deriving (Show)
instance FromJSON Auctions where  
      parseJSON (Object o ) = Auctions <$> o.: "auctions"
      parseJSON _ = mzero

data Auc = Auc {
    auc :: Integer,
    itme :: Int,
    owner ::  String,
    bid :: Integer,
    buyout ::Integer,
    quantity :: Int,
    timeLeft :: String,
    rand :: Integer,
    seed :: Integer
    } deriving (Show )

instance FromJSON Auc where
      parseJSON (Object o ) = Auc <$>
            o .: "auc" <*>
            o .: "item" <*>
            o .: "owner" <*>
            o .: "bid" <*>
            o .: "buyout" <*>
            o .: "quantity" <*>
            o .: "timeLeft" <*>
            o .: "rand" <*>
            o .: "seed"
      parseJSON _ = mzero

main = do
    au<- C.readFile "a.json"
    let x = decode au :: Maybe AuctionInfo
    case x of
        Just a -> do
            {-putStrLn.show $ a-}
            putStrLn .show.length.auctions.alliance $ a
            putStrLn "ok"
        Nothing -> putStrLn "fail"
```

my [json test file](http://pastebin.com/PvtSvst5)

And test steps:

1. save the code , and name it a.hs (or what you want)
2. save the test data ,name it a.json (do not change its name)
3. if you have not install `aeson`, `$ cabal install aseon`
4. `$ ghc a.hs -o a`
5. `$ ./a`

What I get from the output is "fail".

And when I run the command `$ runghc a.hs` for a few times ,
I even got some `ok` and some `fail` mixed together.

I have also tried this code on my linux and 64bit mac ghc, they all output `ok` as I expected.

One of my friends has also tried this code on his 32bit mac ghc, `fail` too. And he told me that he played some black magic to my code and changed one line into

```haskell
 let x = decode $(C.pack. C.unpack) au :: Maybe AuctionInfo
```

then the output is `ok`. But when I did the same black magic, the output is still `fail`.

I just want to make sure is this my bug or a bug of ghc, or how can I determine that.

Comment: You have some Unicode in your test file, this is not a problem under Linux but who knows about other OSs. I've seen some annoying Unicode-related bugs in GHC on Windows. Have you tried to test on ASCII data?

Comment: It is hard to determine whether it is a bug of Unicode. I have a tried to delete one line from my test data, leaving other lines with Chinese characters, then got `OK`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if the behaviour is related to this, but you absolutely shouldn't use `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8` since that's only for 8-bit ASCII data and your input is UTF-8.

Try replacing that import with

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
```

and use `BL.readFile` to read in the data (of course the actual name doesn't matter, but `BL` is the idiomatic shorthand for the lazy bytestring package).

Note that usually you would use `Data.Text` for handling unicode text, but in this case the `aeson` API expects the binary (i.e. `ByteString`) representation and handles decoding the unicode internally.

EDIT: Actually now that I've thought about this some more, I don't think the problem is with using `Char8` after all (although the point stands about not using it for unicode text in general) as you are not doing any conversions from `String` or `Char` (expect for the `C.pack . C.unpack` experiment, which would break all multi-byte characters).